# Trying to shuffle a "Deck" class, doesn't seem to be shuffling

Tags: java

I've written a Deck class and now have to shuffle it, and then print out a few hands to check how it works. However, it doesn't seem to shuffle anything, but rather give the exact same deck.

```
public void makeHands () {
    Deck deck = new Deck ();
    Deck shuffled = shuffleDeck (deck);
    printDeck (subdeck (shuffled, 0, 4));
    printDeck (subdeck (shuffled, 5, 9));
    printDeck (subdeck (shuffled, 10, 14));
    printDeck (subdeck (shuffled, 15, 19));
}

public static int randomInt (int length, int i) {
    double x = Math.random () * length;
    int g = (int) x;
    return g;
}

public Deck shuffleDeck (Deck deck) {
    for (int i=0; i<deck.cards.length; i++) {
        int g = randomInt (deck.cards.length, i);
        swapCards (i, g);
    }
    return deck;
}
}


public void swapCards (int first, int swap) {
         Card temp = cards[first];
         cards[first] = cards[swap];
         cards[swap] = temp;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code looks incomplete.

It looks like you need to pass the deck object to the swapCards method.

swapCards() is referring to a cards array. It is n't clear where this array is declared. Instead you should pass deck to this method and swap deck.cards[first] and deck.cards[swap].